# Reformattiong CSV to WKT

Tags: csv, qgis, wkt

I need help reformatting a CSV file of polygons into a format readable by QGIS.
The data I downloaded has  a bunch of seemingly unnecessary text before the coordinates of the polygons.

The coordinates are formatted like this:

```
{"geodesic":false,"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446],[-124.26664819810578,49.1037998920697],[-124.26718718727625,49.1037998920697],[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446]]]}
```

and I need them to be formatted like this:

```
MULTIPOLYGON [[[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446],[-124.26664819810578,49.1037998920697],[-124.26718718727625,49.1037998920697],[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446]]]
```

Comment: You could write a Python script that parse each of your lines, extracting the coordinates and converting them to the WKT format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: If you know Python, you can quickly read the GeoJSON to Shapely with [`geometry.shape`](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.geometry.shape), then export whatever WKT you need.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have all your coordinates in a text file line by line you'd make a copy of your file, use NotePad++ and go through following steps:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `({"geodesic":false,"type":"Polygon","coordinates":)(.+)(\}$)`
- Replace with: `MULTIPOLYGON \2`
- Search mode: Regular expression
- Click on <kbd>Replace All</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

  Done ...

[image]

```
MULTIPOLYGON [[[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446],...,...,[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446]]]
MULTIPOLYGON [[[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446],...,...,[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446]]]
MULTIPOLYGON [[[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446],...,...,[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446]]]
MULTIPOLYGON [[[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446],...,...,[-124.26718718727625,49.10353039748446]]]
```